# How to pass data from sql to Multiple Middleware and render it all on one page

Tags: sql, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to build a content management system that enables the system administrator to modify all system properties such as metadata for all html pages, but I encountered a difficulty, which is that the data that is sent to ejs is in the form of an object and when I write the ejs format it does not work and the result appears empty
[image]

Settings Controller ↓ Here it works properly

```
// Get all data from the settings to display it on evre page.
exports.data = (req, res, next) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM settings', async (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return next()
        } else {
            const settings = results[0]
            console.log(settings)
            next()
        };
    })
}
```

settings.js route ↓ Here it works properly

```
const express = require("express");
const settingsController = require("../controller/settings")
const router = express.Router();

// get all data from database
router.get('/settings', settingsController.data );

module.exports = router;
```

ejs page contains include elements what i am trying to modify is the html head

index ↓ Here it works properly

```
<%- include('./partials/head'); %>
</head>
<body>
<%- include('./partials/navbar'); %>
<%- include('./partials/footer'); %>
```

page.js route ↓ Here it works properly

```
// use res.render to load up an ejs view file
// index page
                                 settings Middleware ↓ 
router.get('/', authController.isLoggedIn,settingsController.data,indexController.home);
```

head.ejs ↓ here is my problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
                                            Empty ↓
    <meta name="description" content="<%= settings.description %>">
```

Home page from the client side ↓ here is my problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
                               Empty ↓
    <meta name="description" content="">
```

Comment: You controller has no effect, it only logs some information and then calls the next middleware. Why do you need it?

Comment: authController.isLoggedIn To verify that the user is logged in,
settingsController.data To pass the navbar items to display to the user,
indexController.home In order to display upcoming ads on the page
As I said earlier, the system I am working on is trying to make everything in it modifiable and changeable, so I use a large number of Middleware

Comment: I meant to say that `settingsController.data` has no effect. The code that you shared does not pass anything anywhere.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the navbar data to ejs and pass to the next Middleware if it is not possible how can I distribute the work between each Middleware and the second

Comment: Instead of `const settings = results[0]`, write `res.locals.settings = results[0]`. `res.locals` will be available in the next middleware.

Comment: When I checked the code again, I tried the following: 
Settings Controller ↓ 
`const settings = results[0]
            res.settings = settings;
            console.log(settings)
            next()`

Index Controller or indexController.home ↓
`settings: res.settings`
It works thank you